# Perl: Is is possible for a Hash to store mixed variables?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, merge

Quick question:
I would like to store the below variables in a Hash:

```
my %hash1;
my %hash2;
my %hash3;
my @array1;
my @array2;
my @array3;
```

End result being:

```
Hash
    hash1Name
             {key1=>val1,key2=>val2}
    hash2Name
             {key1=>val1,key2=>val2}
    hash3Name
             {key1=>val1,key2=>val2}
    array1Name
             [element1,element2,...]
    array2Name
             [element1,element2,...]
    array3Name
             [element1,element2,...]
```

Why do i want to do this:
Well this is all done in a function (sub) so a want to return all data in a single hash.

Is this possible?

Would it be better to just create a class, which can hold these variables?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store any scalar inside a hash or an array. Scalars include references to arrays or hashes:

```
my $hash = {
  hash1Name => \%hash1,
  hash2Name => \%hash2,
  hash3Name => \%hash3,
  array1Name => \@array1,
  array2Name => \@array2,
  array3Name => \@array3,
}
```

Perl has no type system that would get in your way if you want to do this. But you, the programmer, are now responsible for correctly handling the contents of the hash, regardless of the type. If it enables a cleaner design, you can use OO. But be aware that

1. The underlying object would usually be implemented by such a hash anyway
2. OO for OO's sake unneccessarily complicates code, when basic data structures are enough.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible, and most easily done with lexical variables:

```
sub mysub {
    my %hash1;
    my %hash2;
    my %hash3;
    my @array1;
    my @array2;
    my @array3;
    ...
    my %all = (
         hash1  => \%hash1,
         hash2  => \%hash2,
         array1 => \@array1,
         # etc
    );
    return \%all;
}
```

You return a single scalar value which is a hash reference, containing all the data.

Answer (score 1):

```
my %Hash = (
   hash1Name  => \%hash1,
   hash2Name  => \%hash2,
   hash3Name  => \%hash3,
   array1Name => \@array1,
   array2Name => \@array2,
   array3Name => \@array3,
);
```

But you probably want a reference to a hash:

```
my $Hash = {
   hash1Name  => \%hash1,
   hash2Name  => \%hash2,
   hash3Name  => \%hash3,
   array1Name => \@array1,
   array2Name => \@array2,
   array3Name => \@array3,
};
```